# Обложки аудиозаписей vk

Tags: vkontakte-api

Вытягиваю аудиозаписи с помощью публичного апи. Может кто знает, как достать у аудио ее обложку не юзая id3?

Comment: У аудиозаписей нет публичного апи, как это так вы умудряетесь вытягивать?

Comment: Как же достать обложку из ID3, не используя ID3? Да примерно так же, как достать из холодильника сыр, не используя холодильник. Т.е. никак. Но можно, конечно, взять в другом месте. Только не факт, что это окажется <s>тот же сыр, что в холодильнике</s>, такая же обложка, что в файле.

Comment: У них в официальном API, приватным на данный момент, имеются обложки, хранящиеся на их же сервере, и установлены на определенный трек (если он, например был релизнут на какой-нибудь крупной аудио-платформе.) В их API, при запросе на определенный трек есть параметр с обложками, точно не помню как называется но что-то вроде `thumbnail` или просто `thumb` и там уже имеются ссылки на обложки.

Comment: не могу определить сам запрос за обложкой + передающиеся параметры (

Comment: публичный апи есть, просто генерить правильно токен нужно